# Find count knowing percent of total and some other info

Tags: linear-algebra

Very sorry if this is a stupid question which I should have known how to solve, it certainly feels like something from back in the middle school (it's not home assignment, btw :))

```
*100 units* - which is 40% of total - objects of type A - each object has weight of 5
*150 units* - which is 60% of total - objects of type B - each object has weight of 3
total weight of all units of both types == 950
```

Let's say we have all this info **except the numbers of units** (first piece of info) -- how to calculate this first pieces of info for each type of object (A and B)?

```
*?? units* - which is 40% of total - objects of type A - each object has weight of 5
*?? units* - which is 60% of total - objects of type B - each object has weight of 3
total weight of all units of both types == 950
```

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

- Let $X$ be the total number of units. So we have $0.4X$ units of type $A$ and their total weight would be $0.4X \times 5$.
- Do the same thing for type $B$.
- Add up the weight, solve for $X$.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have $x$ units of type A and $y$ units of type B.

total weight of $x$ units is $5x$
total weight of $y$ units is $3y$

$$5x+3y=950$$
now we need one more equation in terms of $x$ and $y$.

total units are $x+y$

given that $x$ is $40\%$ of $x+y$

$$(x+y)\frac{40}{100}=x$$
$$y=\frac{3x}{2}$$

can you get to the solution from here?